# Shift Change alert Android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am working in a `Android` application in which i want to show alert during shift change,Let say after every 8 hrs. How can I do it?

I have tried a lot, All are working with some major problem. Can i get a tutorial or tip how i can do it. i am giving what i have tried

```
    public class ShiftConfirmService extends Service 
       {

        private NotificationManager mManager;

        @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
       {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
      }

         @Override
        public void onCreate() 
       {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    super.onCreate();
 }

   @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
     @Override
     public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
      {
   super.onStart(intent, startId);
   Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ShiftAlert.class);
   intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent1);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[ALARM MANAGER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)**

Also there are some tutorials on it as follows

1)http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/

2)http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/android-alarmmanager-tutorial.html

3) You can try this code snippet for test of 24 hrs

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ThisApp.this , myService.class);     
       AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ThisApp.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
           calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
       calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
       calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

      alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 24 hours
```

4)http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html

5)http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-alarm-manager-to-start-service.html

Comment: thank you so much,How i can set for every 12 hours, is it like 12*60*60*1000, is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pending intent for particular time.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

For more [Android Notifications - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

set the following code in the activity where you are starting your service:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ThisApp.this , myService.class);     
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ThisApp.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 8*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 8 hours
```

One more thing, you need to make a receiver which starts your service if your device is switched off. For that you also need to make few changes in Android manifest file also.

```
public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  // Restart service every 30 seconds
  private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 300;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        service.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 8*60*60*1000, pending); 

    // service.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
    // REPEAT_TIME, pending);

  }
}
```

Android Manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name="com.fleetcare.MyScheduleReceiver" >
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```